# Spring State Machine Access to StateContext in eventNotAccepted Listener

Tags: java, spring, listener, spring-statemachine

I'm new to Spring State Machine. I have used a `StateMachineListener` for my state machine. How can i access to `StateContext` in `eventNotAccepted` method.

```
@Override
        public void eventNotAccepted(Message<String> event) {

        }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `StateMachineListener.stateContext(StateContext<S, E>)` and listen all `StateContext` changes. From there check `StateContext.getStage()` when it matches `Stage.EVENT_NOT_ACCEPTED`.

Originally when that listener interface were added we didn't have context and later when people wanted access to it we didn't want to break backward compatibility, thus that new method were added.

Comment: And I'd recommend using `StateMachineListenerAdapter` as it guards you against compile errors if we need to modify `StateMachineListener` again.